# Need help in implementing __new__ method for the below scenario

Tags: python

I wanted to know whether the below scenario be available using `__new__` special method. If so, I would like to hear from stackoverflow. I have class name `Listing` which reads records from a file and then convert them in a queries. To be concise, initially the snippet reads all the lines from the file and converts them into list of lists. Again, this list of lists are passed to the loadlist method of Event, which reads each list, unpacks and then set them to class attributes.

For Instance, I have the below three records

```
1|305|8|1851|Gotterdammerung|2008-01-25 14:30:00
2|306|8|2114|Boris Godunov|2008-10-15 20:00:00
3|302|8|1935|Salome|2008-04-19 14:30:0
```

Here, `Listing.py` reads the above content and converts them into queries which is given below

```sql
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('1','305','8','1851','Gotterdammerung','2008-01-25 14:30:00')
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('2','306','8','2114','Boris Godunov','2008-10-15 20:00:00')
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('3','302','8','1935','Salome','2008-04-19 14:30:00')
```

The Whole program of `Listing.py`

```py
class Event:

    def __init__(self,eventid,venueid,catid,dateid,eventname,starttime):
         self.eventid = eventid
         self.venueid = venueid
         self.catid = catid
         self.dateid = dateid
         self.eventname = eventname
         self.starttime = starttime

    def __iter__(self):
        return (i for i in (self.eventid,self.venueid,self.catid,self.dateid,self.eventname,self.starttime))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(tuple(self))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ({!r},{!r},{!r},{!r},{!r},{!r})".format(*self)

    @classmethod
    def loadlist(cls,records):
        return [cls(*record) for record in records]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = []
    with open('tickitdb/allevents_pipe.txt','r') as f:
        records = list(map(lambda s:s.rstrip('\n').split('|'),f.readlines()))

    events = Event.loadlist(records=records)
    with open('events.sql','w+') as f:
        print('writing file')
        for event in events:
            f.write(repr(event)+"\n")
```

When i ran the program, i came across the below error.
`TypeError: __init__() missing 5 required positional arguments:`. And i figured out the root cause behind this. When the program reads the file and converts them into list of records, there was record which is empty hasn't, for instance

```
1.['1','305','8','1851','Gotterdammerung','2008-01-25 14:30:00']
2.['2','306','8','2114','Boris','Godunov','2008-10-15 20:00:00']
3.['3','302','8','1935','Salome','2008-04-19 14:30:0']
4.['']
```

For the 4th record, there are no values. So, to avoid such errors, i decided to make use of `__new__` special method. I can achieve same functionality by putting the `if` condition and then checking whether the list is empty or not. But then i wondering how to make use of **new** special method to avoid such scenarios. With little knowledge of python, i have filled the **new** special method, but then I came across the below error

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

```py
   def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        if len(args) != 0:
            instance = Event.__new__(cls,*args,**kwargs)
            return instance
```

Can we filter the records using the `__new__` special method ?

Comment: @Norrius. Ok I wanted to know whether this can be done or not. And thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is totally possible. But you will need to initialize the instance by yourself once it returns from **new** .
I  fixed your code as under

Given listing.txt

```
1|305|8|1851|Gotterdammerung|2008-01-25 14:30:00
2|306|8|2114|Boris Godunov|2008-10-15 20:00:00
3|302|8|1935|Salome|2008-04-19 14:30:0

4|302|8|1935|Salome|2008-04-19 14:30:0
```

```
class Event:

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        breakpoint()
        if len(*args) > 1:
            instance = object.__new__(cls)
            breakpoint()
            return instance
        else:
            return None

    def __init__(self,eventid,venueid,catid,dateid,eventname,starttime):
        self.eventid = eventid
        self.venueid = venueid
        self.catid = catid
        self.dateid = dateid
        self.eventname = eventname
        self.starttime = starttime

    def __iter__(self):
        return (i for i in (self.eventid,self.venueid,self.catid,self.dateid,self.eventname,self.starttime))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(tuple(self))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ({!r},{!r},{!r},{!r},{!r},{!r})".format(*self)

    @classmethod
    def loadlist(cls, records):
        breakpoint()
        return [cls.__init__(*record) for record in records  ]

def initialize(e,eventid,venueid,catid,dateid,eventname,starttime):
    e.eventid = eventid
    e.venueid = venueid
    e.catid = catid
    e.dateid = dateid
    e.eventname = eventname
    e.starttime = starttime
    return e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    records = []
    events = []
    with open('listing.txt', 'r') as f:
        records = list(map(lambda s: s.rstrip('\n').split('|'), f.readlines()))
    for record in records:
        breakpoint()
        e = Event.__new__(Event, record)
        breakpoint()
        if e:
            events.append(initialize(e, *record))
    with open('events.sql','w+') as f:
        print('writing file')
        for event in events:
            f.write(repr(event)+"\n")
```

## OUTPUT

events.sql

```
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('1','305','8','1851','Gotterdammerung','2008-01-25 14:30:00')
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('2','306','8','2114','Boris Godunov','2008-10-15 20:00:00')
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('3','302','8','1935','Salome','2008-04-19 14:30:0')
INSERT INTO EVENT (EVENTID,VENUEID,CATID,DATEID,EVENTNAME,STARTTIME) VALUES ('4','302','8','1935','Salome','2008-04-19 14:30:0')
```

Answer (score 1):

So I would solve it like this:

```
class Event:
      def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) != 0:
          return super(Event, cls).__new__(cls)
        else:
          return None

      def print(self):
        print("a " + str(self.a))
        print("b "  + str(self.b))


c = Event(1, 2)
if c is None:
  print("do some stuff here if it is empty")
```

If you initialize Event with no parameters, it would return None according to len(args) != 0. Otherwise the instance is returned. Hope that helps.